# Update DNS using Powershell on Linux with OpenSSH public key authentication

Tags: linux, powershell, powershell-remoting, openssh

I want to run some commands from a Linux server to remotely execute PowerShell module like DNSserver on a Windows machine to retrieve DNS information. I am using OpenSSH to SSH from Linux to Windows.

I have PowerShell 6.2.3 on both Windows server and Linux server. I started from Linux:

```
>pwsh
PS /home/user1> Enter-PSSession -HostName WinServer-IP -UserName user2
```

If I don't setup the key authentication on the Windows site (add public key in the `C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys` file, and set the correct permissions on the file), PowerShell will ask me for user2 password. After I enter the password, I am on the Windows server, and I can run my PowerShell scripts and they all working fine.

But if I setup the key auth - add public key in the `C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys` file, and set the correct permissions on the file. PowerShell will not ask for user2 password and I get the same prompt as above,

I can do something like `Get-Module` etc. but when I run my script that does:

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName 'DNSServer-IP' -ZoneName 'example.net' -RRType A
```

I got the error:

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord : Failed to get the zone information for
example.net. on server DNSServer-IP.
At C:\Users\user2\scripts\retrieve_ips.ps1:1 char:1
+ Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName 'DNSServer-IP' -ZoneName 'ex ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (example.net.:root/Microsoft/Wind\u2026erverResourceRecord) [Get-DnsServerResourceRecord], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WIN32 5,Get-DnsServerResourceRecord
```

It seems like the SSH public key authentication does not really get me in as "users", but I can not find out what it is.

user2 is a local user on the Windows server, but I have to add it to the Active Directory as AD needs to know this user before it will allow user2 to run DNSserver module...

What did I do wrong, or missed?

Without the SSH public key authentication, the same script works and I could get the A records our of the DNS server.

Comment: Going out on a limb I would suspect that password authentication logs you in as the domain user, whereas public key authentication logs you in as the local user. Local user and domain user are different entities, and you cannot "add" a local account to AD by creating an AD account of the same name. They're still different entities, and apparently only the AD user has access to the DNS server.

Comment: Correct. I switched to a domain user and the whole process worked.

Comment: I tried to use a domain user and add the user's key to the win server for authentication. Login works with but can not run dnsserver module in powershell. Tried to use WinRM, same result...   So there is no way to execute DNS related modules remotely?